# Generate bezier surface as sub-patches

Tags: c++, multithreading, math, geometry, bezier

I have written a small C++ program to generate bezier surface using 4x4 control points.

What I want to do next is to parallelize this process and break the whole surface into sub-patches where each thread will only generate coordinates based on a boundary(bbox) assigned to it.

sample code:

```
for(i=0;i<steps;i++)
{
  float u = i/(steps-1);
  for(j=0;j<steps;j++)
  {
   float v = j/(steps-1);
   Point P = calculate_bezier(u,v);
  }
}
```

calculate_bezier is a function that returns a point on the surface based on the control points. Variable "steps" decides how fine the surface is tesslated.

Here's a not-so-good picture showing what I want to acheive:
[image]

Each color represents a small bounding box assigned to a thread, which then executes the above snippet of code and generates bezier points in respective areas.  I know min/max of these bboxes.

I wanted to ask HOW to do it. I mean, how to restrict the bezier-coordinate generation process only to a bounding box area? Given the bbox bounds for each thread, how will this affect the u and v values?

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Are you looking for a 2D version of de Casteljau's algorithm?

Comment: No I do have the co-ordinate generation in place. Right now I can generate 2D/3D coordinates and generate a surface out of it.  What I want to do is paralleize this process and speed up the whole computation.  What I planned to do is break the whole process into different threads  Each thread gets a bbox dimention, generates coordinates only in that region, in this way I can generate very big patches quickly.  In the figure, each color represents a bbox assigned to a thread.

Comment: You still haven't told us what your question is. Go ahead and do what you plan to do, it sounds like a reasonable idea.

Comment: Damn, sorry, I wanted to ask HOW to do it.  I mean, how to restrict the bezier-coordinate generation process only to a bounding box area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to split up the work by bounding the output vertices. While intersecting a bezier patch with a bounding box is possible, it's not easy or efficient. It would be a much better idea to bound the UV coordinates instead.

Comment: Yes, and this is what I'm not able to figure out.  How can I bound my UV coordinates with the bbox of the threads?

Comment: Why bother? Just split the UV area into equal (in UV-space) squares, and don't worry about whether their XYZ bounding boxes are equal-sized or whether they overlap.

Comment: Hi Ben, I generate these bboxes at runtime with a kd-tree, these bboxes might not be equal, there might not be 4 bboxes as I depict in the figure, there might be more than 4. I think I should give each thread a portion of UV but this is where I'm struck.  I want to map these bboxes to the UV.

Comment: But why divide in XYZ space instead of UV space? Why do you care what bounding box each thread computes? Heck, just have thread x, out of n total, compute the mesh within the UV rectangle `[x/n, 0]-[(x+1)/n, 1]`.

Comment: Hi Ben, it worked, thanks! But I did use bboxes, like I mentioned before I wanted to have uneven bboxes for different threads dividing UV uniformly was not an option for me.  However, I did scale the bboxes into UV range and use these bounds to control which thread loads what.